# Decremeting one from a number represent as a vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, operator-overloading, subtraction

I am trying to decrement a number, which can be infinitely long and is represented in a vector, by 1. As a small example:

```
vector<int> v1 = {5, 0, 0, 0};
```

After subtracting one from the end, the result should be:

```
vector<int> v1 = {4, 9, 9, 9};
```

This is my current code:

```
int size = v1.size();
bool carry = false;

for (int i = size - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    if (v1.at(i) == 0) {
        v1.at(i) = 9;

        if (v1.at(0) == 1) {
            v1.at(0) = 0;
        }

        carry = true;
    } else {
        v1.at(i) -= 1;
        carry = false;
    }
}

if (carry == true && v1.at(0) == 0) {
    v1.erase(v1.begin());
} else if (carry == true) {
    v1.at(0) -= 1;
}

return v1;
```

When I test it, everything works fine, except numbers like 11119. They turn out to be 00019. Is there anything I could tweak?

Comment: The algorithm is wrong, it doesn't need tweaking it needs rewriting. Think about how you would do this by hand, pretend you're eight years old again and are learning how to do this for the first time. Then whatever method you use, code that.

Comment: Learn how to step through your code in a debugger. Seriously, that's a skill that allows you to solve problems like this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you didn't think through the logic clearly.

Here's what needs to happen.

If the last number is 0, it needs to be changed to 9 and a carry has to be maintained.
Repeat until no carry needs to be maintained.

That logic is best implemented using a `do - while` loop. Here's what I came up with.

```
int size = v.size();
bool carry = true;
int i = size - 1;
do
{
   if (v.at(i) == 0)
   {
      v.at(i) = 9;
   }
   else
   {
      v.at(i)--;
      carry = false;
   }
   --i;
}
while ( carry == true && i >= 0);
```

Here's a complete program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void test(std::vector<int> v)
{
   int size = v.size();
   bool carry = true;
   int i = size - 1;
   do
   {
      if (v.at(i) == 0)
      {
         v.at(i) = 9;
      }
      else
      {
         v.at(i)--;
         carry = false;
      }
      --i;
   }
   while ( carry == true && i >= 0);

   for ( auto item : v )
   {
      std::cout << item << " ";
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   test({1, 1, 1, 1, 9});
   test({5, 0, 0, 0, 0});
}
```

and its output

```
1 1 1 1 8
4 9 9 9 9
```

See it working at https://ideone.com/lxs1vz.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was having trouble with the algorithm... Also, I was thinking of using a while instead of a do-while, but that makes much more sense.

Comment: @MattThompson, you're welcome. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

A subtraction as you tried to do, could be done like this:

```
#include <iterator>

std::vector<int> v1 = {5, 0, 0, 0};

for (std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator i = v1.rbegin(); i != v1.rend(); i++) {
    *i -= 1;
    if (*i < 0) {
      *i = 9;
    }
    else {
      break;
    }
}
```